# how can i connect to document DB from Azure ML

Tags: azure, machine-learning, nosql

Is there any data source URL for Document Db to the Azure ML Data reader?
when i try to give the following URL
https://DBName.documents.azure.com:443/

It is asking for authorization
Does anyone tried giving document DB URL in Azure ML Portal(Reader Module)?
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Haven't tried it yet and don't know if you have done it, but what about using the DocumentDB auth key?

Comment: If the answer I provided is correct, please mark as "answer"

Answer (score 1):

Document DB is not supported out of the box by Azure Machine Learning currently.

I think the easiest current work around would be creating a web endpoint that provides all of the data.  If it is very large data, maybe and endpoint that can provide subsets your webserver can support.  This is a work around as AzureML does support web endpoints to query data from.  You can add query support to your .net endpoints.